# window.print() not working in a SharePoint 2013 page

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm fairly new to these things, and I've searched for answers, but couldn't find any.

I created a page on SharePoint 2013 that generates ICE (In Case of Emergency) cards. The code below works on its own, i.e. as a separate HTML file outside SP, but when I paste it into Script Editor web part (tried CEWP as well), the print window simply doesn't open. The *generateCard* function works without issues, but *printCard* doesn't - the Print dialog never pops up.

Do you have any idea what am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<html>
    <h1>ICE Card Generator</h1>
    <p>Enter your details in the form below and click <em>Generate card</em>. After your card has been generated, you can print it.</p>
<form>
    Your name:<input type="text" id="name">
    <br>Your phone number:<input type="text" id="phone">
    <br>Blood type: <input type="text" id="blood">
    <br>Emergency contact name:<input type="text" id="emergencyName">
    <br>Emergency contact's phone number: <input type="text" id="emergencyPhone">
</form>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="generateCard()">Generate card</button><br>
<br>
<div id="card">
  <h1 id="card_my_details">Card holder</h1>
  <p>Name: <span id="cardName">/</span>
  <p>Email: <span id="cardPhone">/</span>
  <p>Blood type: <span id="cardBlood">/</span>
  <h1 id="card_emergency_contacts">Emergency contacts</h1></span>
  <p>Emergency contact: <span id="cardEmergencyName">/</span>
  <p>Emergency contact's phone number: <span id="cardEmergencyPhone">/</span>
  </div>
<br>
<button type="button" click="printCard()">Print card</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/ice_script.js">
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function generateCard() {
    document.getElementById('cardName').innerHTML =
                document.getElementById("name").value;

    document.getElementById('cardPhone').innerHTML =
                document.getElementById("phone").value;

    document.getElementById('cardBlood').innerHTML =
                document.getElementById("blood").value;

    document.getElementById('cardEmergencyName').innerHTML =
                document.getElementById("emergencyName").value;

    document.getElementById('cardEmergencyPhone').innerHTML =
                document.getElementById("emergencyPhone").value;

    }


    function printCard() {
      var thisWillBePrinted = document.getElementById("card").innerHTML;
      var everythingOnPage = document.body.innerHTML;

      document.body.innerHTML = thisWillBePrinted;
      window.print();
      document.body.innerHTML = everythingOnPage;

    }
```

There's also some CSS, but I think it's relevant for the question at hand - how to get the Print dialog to appear? It doesn't work in any browser.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct attribute name to handle click events is `onclick` and not `click`.

You should change

```
<button type="button" click="printCard()">Print card</button>
```

into

```
<button type="button" onclick="printCard()">Print card</button>
```

---

**Notes**

You might want to use replace your inline event handler with an `addEventListener()` method to improve readability.

```
<button type="button" id="printButton">Print card</button>
```

---

```
document.getElementById("printButton").addEventListener('click', function () {
    printCard();
}
```

[Onclick Reference (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)

Comment: Thanks, @Marco! This is probably a typo on my behalf somewhere between trying it out on its own and pasting the code into SP... It works now. Thanks for the MDN link as well, I'll have a look.